# C and C++ pass by pointer and pass by reference confusion

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference

So I understand how to pass in addresses to a C function to avoid passing in the value. But what I do not understand is passing in by reference in C++. My lack of understanding comes from C where, if you were to pass in the variables by reference, you would just get a nonsense `int` value based on the address. Such as if you did:

```
int x = 5;
int* p = x;
int y = p;
```

The `y` would be a nonsense `int` value. So I do not understand C++ pass by reference based on the above logic. Is there some compiler identification of what you are trying to do so it compiles it in a way that makes it equivalent to the C code? See below for C and C++ pass by pointer and by reference:

```
// C pass by pointer value
void main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    swap(&a, &b);
    }

void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

// C++ pass by reference
void main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    swap(a, b);
    }

void swap(int &a, int &b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Comment: C++ references are just abstractions of pointers. The C++ compiler will probably produce the same code, whether you are using references or pointers.

Comment: That is not necessarily the case. If the compiler can resolve the names inline then it can simply have both names for the same value in its symbol lookup table.

Comment: How pointers and references are implemented is not specified by the standard. It's all up to the implementation you are using (i.e. compiler, cpu, etc.). My guess is that they are implemented the same way in most cases. See https://godbolt.org/z/5Ws8zYcsY

Comment: "*My lack of understanding comes from C where if you were to pass in the variables by reference you would just get a nonsense int value based on address*" - C doesn't have references at all, only pointers. C++ has references.

Comment: It is not wrong to refer to references in C. You get a reference by dereferencing a pointer. C does not have named _direct_ references.

Answer (score 5):

You are asking a question that starts holy wars.

#### Objects

An **object** is an instance of some kind of thing: it has its own memory and everything. A lot of objects in our code get *names*.

```
int number_of_birds_in_hand = 0;
std::string users_name = "Fred";
```

You see the pattern: type, name, value.

The name is a ***direct reference*** to the object, or *alias*.

#### Pointers

*Pointers* are ***indirect references*** to an object. They are indirect because they are themselves objects, having names and values all their own:

```
const char * filename = "hello.txt";
```

We tend to confuse it because it *looks* like `filename` has the value `"hello.txt"`, but that is not the case. `filename`’s value is the *address* of the text. We can change that address any time:

```
filename = "goodbye.txt";
```

(Like any variable in C and C++ we can tell the compiler not to let us do that, with: `const char * const filename`.)

We ***dereference*** a pointer to get a direct reference to the object. The direct reference has no name, but it resolves to the same as having that object’s name.

```
int x = 12;
int * y = &x;
*y = -7;
```

The construct `*y` resolves to a direct reference (or alias) to `x`: accessing `*y` is the same as accessing `x`. But `y` itself is only a reference to its own object value.

#### References

C++ adds a new construct, called a ***reference***. From the language point of view, that is exactly what it is: another name for an object.

```
int x = 12;
int & y = x;
y = -7;
```

Here, both `x` and `y` are aliases (or direct references) to the same object!

#### Holy Wars

The way we speak about these things gets people going. The C++ Standard has one way of doing it. CS literature throughout time has another. Very intelligent, knowledgeable people can vary in their opinions on this topic.

I personally have no problem referring to a pointer as a reference when talking in C. But in C++ such language gets confused with true references (not the indirect references that pointers are).

A common argument people like to have is whether references are really pointers or not. The answer is that *it depends*. Sometimes they are, sometimes they aren’t.

It is an infantile argument, because *from the point of view provided by the C++ language* they are different things. How they work underneath really only matters to the people who make compilers.

And then you have the whole *pass-by-pointer* holy war too... but best leave that one for a different SO question.

#### Final Thoughts

The trick is to understand what people mean when they refer to these things, and if you are unsure just ask. If someone gets loud and angry about the way you referred to it, just try to use the terminology that they used. They can go have baby cows without you.

In common C++, you have object values, pointers, and references, and depending on whom you ask, never shall they be confused. If you are unsure, just say that you passed a pointer to a function so that you could dereference it to get the target value, heh.

Comment: Thank you for that in depth response! So C++ added reference as a new construct.

Comment: Well.... new is relative they've been a part of the language for a long time. I just think there are too many books around that still teach the "older" style C++ where only pointers are used.

Comment: “New” in the sense that C++ has it and C did not. It’s an old new... I guess...  :-D   Sadly the book problem is never going to go away. Even SO here has its own C and C++ book problem...

Comment: C/C++  are often called "high-level assemblers", because they're designed around hardware.  This answer reveals that C++ is also a compiler-oriented language, that is, it has many features that can be fully understood only if one has some idea about how a compiler works. Another examples are the move semantics and the weird "inline" keyword.  This "compiler-orientedness" is indirect in that it never forces specific compiler techniques, just makes them possible. Like pointers to members (very different from standard pointers) or virtual functions (do they go with a virtual table?).

Comment: I don't think it says that at all. References are a high-level language feature that has always existed in some form across a wide swath of languages. The problem lies in people's minds: they are too busy trying to self-engineer the inner workings of C and C++ to consider that they are designed over a virtual machine, just like Pascal or Java or BF. And while it is true that that VM works nicely with current hardware, for some reason people can't just accept the world as the language presents it and instead try to force it through a backwards viewing...